# CakePHP Hashing Passwords

Tags: cakephp, passwords, password-encryption

I am using CakePHP 2.3.4 with Basic authenticate.

My question is if the same passwords are hashed, are the two hashed password strings are the same? If not, which authenticate or password hasher can generate the same hashed passwords with same passwords?

Comment: Why would you want to have this behavior, it just weakens security?!

Answer (score 0):

According to the CakePHP manual

> In basic authentication, the username and password are transmitted as plain-text to the server.

So they are the same but they are not encrypted.

I personally do not recommend having the same hashed password if your application will be widely used. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/85075

Edit: Also I forgot if using the digest authentication gives you the same hashed password so hopefully someone can chime in on that.